# Lyapunov Exponents vs Lyapunov Function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, lyapunov-functions

Suppose I have a system of differential equations $\dot {\vec x} = \vec f(\vec x)$, and that there is an equilibrium point $\vec x = 0$. Moreover, suppose I know the Lyapunov exponents of the equilibrium $\vec x = 0$. Is there a way to calculate the Lyapunov function $V(\vec x)$ given the Lyapunov exponents?